# SQL запрос на получение данных из 3-х таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть три таблицы - Users(поля - name, id), Accounts(поля - id, user_id), Transactions(поля id, account_id, amount).
Связки по FK следующие:

1) user.id <- accounts.user_id

2) accounts.id <- transactions.account_id.

Задача - вывести именя пользователей, id счета и сумму всех транзакций по этому счету.
Мое понимание запроса:

```
SELECT user.name, accounts.id, SUM(transactions.amount) WHERE user.id=accounts.user_id AND accounts.id = transactions.account_id;
```

Но мне сказали, что это неверно. Как же тогда будет выглядеть запрос?

Comment: А где группировка?

Comment: FROM - отсутствует. GROUP BY - отсутствует. Правильно сказали...

Answer (score 2):

Ваш «запрос» во-первых не индентирован, а во-вторых вообще не является
верным *SQL*.  Что же касается задания, верное решение такое:

```sql
SELECT MAX(users.name) AS user_name
     , accounts.id AS account_id
     , SUM(transactions.amount) AS amount_sum
  FROM users
       INNER JOIN accounts
               ON accounts.user_id = users.id
       INNER JOIN transactions
               ON transactions.account_id = accounts.id
 GROUP BY accounts.id
;
```

Comment: я пока что плохо разбираюсь в SQL, потому и не смог написать верно